# RealmMigrationNeededException when adding RealmList<Int> (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-migration

I want to add a *primitive* list to an existing model but I get an exception.
Attention: This is all done **it Kotlin**.

Here's the model:

```
open class Foo(
    @PrimaryKey var id: Int = 0
) : RealmObject()
```

Now I want to add the following field:

```
var idList: RealmList<Int> = RealmList()
```

This could be an empty list so I initialize it with a blank `RealmList` (which used to work for non-primitive-list-fields).

My migration looks like this:

```
schema.get("Foo")
        ?.addRealmListField("idList", Int::class.java)
```

---

When running the app, I get an `RealmMigrationNeededException`:

> Migration is required due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'Foo.idList' has been made optional.

---

I can work around this by adding `@Required` to the new field in the model but I'm not sure if the list can still be empty / null then.

What's the correct way to add a primitive-list to a model and whats the correct migration for this?

Comment: What version of Realm do you use?

Comment: You can try `Int::class.javaPrimitiveType)` although considering this is a `RealmList<Integer>` you might just want to add the `@Required`. It just means this RealmList cannot contain `null` as a value.

Comment: The javadoc will be updated https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your migration is correct. If you don't want the list to be able to contain `null` as a value (considering it is a `RealmList<Integer>`, where `Integer` can be null), you should add `@Required` annotation.

Comment: Hmm, so to make this clear (your text is confusing): A `RealmList<Int>` *cannot* contain `null` but one with `Integer` can? And if I want to use this kotlin-non-null-type I *have to* add `@Required`? This would be fine for me. THX.

Comment: No, I meant that @Required means you can't store null as an Integer

Comment: confusion complete... is the following correct? When using `Integer` I *could* use `null` but adding `@Required` prevents this / using `Int` (without `?`) cannot use `null` by default. Right? But when I don't want `nulls`, why do I need `@Require` when using `Int`? Is it because `Int` and `Integer` are equal for Realm? So what`s correct then when I want non-null-int values?

Comment: For a RealmList of primitive, required specified whether you can store `Null` as a value inside the list.